# DDR4 SODIMM Compatability (Are there different SODIMM variations?)

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr, sodimm

I am looking to get an 8GB DDR4 SODIMM module to upgrade my laptop's RAM. I looked it up on Crucial and the recommended module was this: https://www.crucial.com/memory/ddr4/ct8g4sfs8266/ct13500791

As you can see the notch in the pins is in the middle and slightly to the left. However, I have also found slightly cheaper DDR4 SODIMM 8GB modules that run at 2400Mhz instead (which is the original RAM speed), but the notch is in the middle towards the right, which makes me wonder if there will be a compatibility issue when I try to fit the new RAM in. 
Example: https://www.newegg.com/p/0RN-00PC-00006?&quicklink=true

I can't find a pin count on the Crucial module, though the 2400 is 260 pins on Newegg. Are these different variations of the SODIMM format? Or will either work in any SODIMM DDR4 slot? If not, how do I tell which one is correct short of taking my laptop apart and looking? And yes, I know it is slightly preferable to have all the same clock speed across RAM, and that it will only run at the top speed of the slowest stick, but I'm also considering switching all of the RAM out to 2666Mhz so it would be good to know.

Comment: When you flip the _Nano Tech_ "DOLGIX" over, the slot will be towards the left also. The great difference is __the speed__. I believe both are good "Nano Tech" and "Crucial" trusted RAM makers.

Comment: Won't it be facing the wrong way then?

Comment: No, if you spin the memory around, it will not face the wrong way. It should work correctly. They just placed it like that to show everyone the label(s)